# Display percentage in a pie chart with ChartKick and Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chartkick

I am displaying a pie chart with ChartKick and Chart.js and it looks good.  I would like to display the percentage of each slice in addition to the numeric value.  I have found references on how to do it with Google charts and with HighCharts, but I am unable to find a way for Chart.js while still using ChartKick.

Anyone got a way to do it or docs to explain how?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the each pie chart slice label/text in rails 7 using chartkick gem, we should use the chartkick adapter setting to google or highcharts because chartkick gem is built on top of chart.js, google charts and highcharts so it might not support the options we might expected to work seamlessly...

Here's the Pie chart with options passed as hash

**
<%= pie_chart @partner_category_chart_data, title: "Quotes filtered by partner category", adapter: "google", legend: "bottom",
library: {
pieSliceText: "value-and-percentage"
}
%>
**